# Cannot get the column specific timestamp to display on checkbox

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I have set up a Google sheet for attendance of Employees on which clicking on the checkbox, the current time is recorded.

I cannot get the specific timestamp in the respective columns when the checkbox is ticked.

Clicking on a different checkbox also change the timestamp for previously checked checkboxes.

I have used this formula here : `=If(B2 = TRUE,now(),"")`
and used filter handle to apply the formula for other rows underneath.

I have used this formula: `=If(B2 = TRUE,now(),"")`
The sheet can be seen here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p6jmnHXtCu2m7BdLfC-23A51MrwkJJJpXidpbsDwxfU/edit?usp=sharing

I want to record the current timestamp, for each row.
i.e on clicking of the checkbox the current time should be changed/recorded only for the column in the same row and not for other records.

Comment: The problem is with the `now()` formula which you are using. It will refresh it's self every time the sheet recalculates. I am not sure what you want is possible without writing code to enter the timestamp at the time the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this needs to be done with the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
      nextCell.setValue(newDate);
   }
}
```

---

### how to add a script to your spreadsheet

- go to **Tools**
- select **Script editor**

  [image: 0]
- copy paste the script
- save the project under some name

  [image]
- click on run icon and authorise it...

  [image]
- select your account

  [image]
- click on **Advanced**

  [image]
- select **Go to * (unsafe)**

  [image]
- click on **Allow** and return to your sheet (you can close script window/tab)

  [image]

Comment: I see, but how can I insert this formula in google sheet? Does google has a way to implement this?

Comment: Thanks @player0 it worked. You are awesome! However, is there a way, that we can disable manual edit or input in the date field and the date should be populated only if the checkbox is ticked.?